# what does the symbol "?" mean and how can i edit that page?

Tags: pages, urls

I have a site I can't edit the page of it the page contains the following link
`https://www.testsite.com/?booking`
how can I edit my booking page

Answer (score 0):

`?` means the start of the variables that are accessable via PHP on the page called.  The page `https://www.testsite.com/` will be called, and `booking` variable will be accessible globally throughout the PHP script.  In this case, the homepage script will be run.  The `$_GET['booking']` index will be set (to `NULL`), and will (usually) be accessible also at `$_REQUEST['booking']`.

Now, this URI could very well be a dead link if you found it published somewhere in your code.  In the case that it does represent a post or page, you can edit it in the back-end admin panel by clicking on either "Posts" or "Pages" in the left hand admin column.  After doing so, you will get a list of the posts/pages on which you can click on its appearance in the table and edit its permalink.